# Joining pairs of key-value with pairs of key-map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am having this **dataset**:

```
(apple,1)
(banana,4)
(orange,3)
(grape,2)
(watermelon,2)
```

, and the **other dataset** is:

```
(apple,Map(Bob -> 1))
(banana,Map(Chris -> 1))
(orange,Map(John -> 1))
(grape,Map(Smith -> 1))
(watermelon,Map(Phil -> 1))
```

I aiming to **combine** both sets to get:

```
(apple,1,Map(Bob -> 1))
(banana,4,Map(Chris -> 1))
(orange,3,Map(John -> 1))
(grape,2,Map(Smith -> 1))
(watermelon,2,Map(Phil -> 1))
```

---

The **code** I have:

```
...  
val counts_firstDataset = words.map(word => 
(word.firstWord, 1)).reduceByKey{case (x, y) => x + y}
```

Second dataset:

```
...
val counts_secondDataset  = secondSet.map(x => (x._1,
x._2.toList.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)))
```

I tried to use the **join method** `val joined_data = counts_firstDataset.join(counts_secondDataset)` but did not work because the join takes pair of [K,V]. How would I get around this issue?

Comment: @philantrovert RDDs

Comment: Got it. I should have read the question completely.

Comment: What data structure did you use to store those datasets? List, set etc. ?

Comment: @fcat: both datasets are tuples. First one: tuple of (String, int).. Second one: tuple of (String, Map) .. aiming to get tuple of (String, int, Map)

Comment: I see. But what I am asking is the type of `counts_firstDataset` and `counts_secondDataSet`.

Comment: The question is unclear because your first and second dataset do not match with the transformations that you have provided towardsthe end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is just to convert to `DataFrames` and then `join`:

```
import spark.implicits._
val counts_firstDataset = words
  .map(word => (word.firstWord, 1))
  .reduceByKey{case (x, y) => x + y}
  .toDF("type", "value")

val counts_secondDataset = secondSet
  .map(x => (x._1,x._2.toList.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)))
  .toDF("type_2","map")

counts_firstDataset
  .join(counts_secondDataset, 'type === 'type_2)
  .drop('type_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

As first element (name of fruits) of both the lists are in the same order, you can combine the two lists of tuples using **zip** and then use **map** to change the list to a tuple in the following way:

```
counts_firstDataset.zip(counts_secondDataset)
  .map(vk => (vk._1._1, vk._1._2, vk._2._2))
```